# 'equals()' between objects of inconvertible types 'int' and 'TextWatcher' error

Tags: java, android

i have a strange error that i can't solve. The error is : 'equals()' between objects of inconvertible types 'int' and 'TextWatcher'. And this is my code:

```
if( textWatcher_ans.equals(R.string.editText_7)){
    Toast.makeText(getApplication().getBaseContext(),
                   (R.string.Good),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

            private final TextWatcher textWatcher_ans = new TextWatcher(){
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                textView_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (s.length() == 0) {
                    textView_name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    textView_name.setText("You have entered : " + editText_surname.getText());
                }
            }
```

I'm pretty stuck and i dont know what to do.
can someone pleas help me?

Comment: Here it is @Erik-JanWestendorp

Comment: What is your aim here? Right now you're comparing the `TextWatcher` object to an integer (an integer that maps to the string resource), which I'm fairly certain isn't what you want.

Comment: What i want is someting that the user typed in equals my string. @asadmshah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your aim is to display the `R.string.Good` message if the text in `editText_surname` matches `R.string.editText_7` then try something like this:

First attach the TextWatcher to `editText_surname`:

```
editText_surname.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher_ans);
```

In your `afterTextChangedMethod`:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if (s.length() == 0) {
        textView_name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     } else {
        textView_name.setText("You have entered : " + s.toString());
     }

    if (s.toString().equals(context.getString(R.string.editText_7)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication().getBaseContext(),
               (R.string.Good),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! But when i entered this code into the file i got this error: Cannot resolve symbol 'Context'.

Comment: Oh wait, i didn't declared the context. Thanks a lot!!!! I really appreciate it!! @asadmshah

Comment: @JeroenBoot No problem. If this answer has solved your problem please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark located underneath the downvote button.

Comment: Done! Thanks again! @asadmshah